# What can we expect to observe if we were able to observe de Broglie wavelength of massive bodies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavelength, matter

I have seen the famous question where they ask us calculate the de Broglie wavelength of a moving ball but it comes out to be too small and hence we conclude that it is too small to measure by known experiments.

But what are we expecting to measure if say such an experiment was possible?

I find it very weird that big object may have some wave-like properties associated with them and may occupy more than one position in space.

So can someone provide some idea over what do we really mean by wavelengths of a big objects and what exact wave-like characters should they possess?

Comment: we could  expect the massive bodies two be present at multiple positions simultaneously (if the wavelength would have been observed) $ :)$